# Nginx 1.25.2 HTTP/3 works over CURL, but doesn't work in any browser

Tags: nginx, networking, ubuntu-22.04, quic, http3

I am trying to configure **nginx 1.25.2** with **HTTP/3** support on **Ubuntu 22.04**. I build it using **BoringSSL** library. But when I try to connect to my server using browser, I don't get anything.("Unable to connect" in Firefox and "This site can't be reached" in Chrome for example).

Here is **nginx -V** output:

```
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1 (compatible; BoringSSL) (running with BoringSSL) 
TLS SNI support enabled configure arguments: 
--prefix=/etc/nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-debug 
--with-http_v3_module --with-cc-opt=-I../boringssl/include 
--with-ld-opt='-L../boringssl/build/ssl -L../boringssl/build/crypto'
```

Here is my server part in **nginx.conf**:

```
 server {
        #listen 443 ssl 
        #http2 on;
        listen 443 quic reuseport;
        server_name  example_myserver;
        ssl_certificate cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key key.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
        location / {
            add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400';
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
```

Using above config I can get HTTP/3 response using **http3 curl**:

```
HTTP/3 200 
server: nginx/1.25.2
date: Wed, 23 Aug 2023 08:12:55 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 615
last-modified: Tue, 22 Aug 2023 14:25:41 GMT
etag: "64e4c565-267"
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
accept-ranges: bytes
```

and using https://github.com/cloudflare/quiche http3client tool I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I reach the same server via browser, nothing there("Unable to connect" in Firefox and "This site can't be reached" in Chrome). UFW is turned **off** completely. By the way, **http1** and **http2** works without any problem. Maybe someone had similar problem and could help me or maybe I missed something? I will be grateful for any useful info.

Comment: "nothing there" is not a good description of what actually happenned.

Comment: "Unable to connect" in Firefox(as I wrote at the start) and "This site can't be reached" in Chrome

Comment: These will connect using HTTP/1.1 over TCP before trying HTTP/3 whereas I believe the successful clients both attempt Quic only. You need to uncomment `#listen 443 ssl`

Comment: If I uncomment `#listen 443 ssl` It connects only over HTTP/1.1

Comment: Yes the FIRST request from a browser is always made using HTTP/1.1 - open your webdeveloper tools and see what happens after that.

Comment: I refresh it multiple times, nothing changes. The cache is disabled btw